# Using select count(*) in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
    String dd_webCofig = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["server132"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection ddlistconn = new SqlConnection(dd_webCofig);
    ddlistconn.Open();

    string ddlist = "select count(*) from jud_order where complex_name=@a and case_no=@b and sign=@c and jud_order_date=@d and user_code=@e";
    SqlCommand ddlistCmd = new SqlCommand(ddlist, ddlistconn);
    ddlistCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", "a");
    ddlistCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", "a");
    ddlistCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("c", "a");
    ddlistCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d", "a");
    ddlistCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("e", "a");

    SqlDataReader myReader = ddlistCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I am having the above query which returns number of rows, now my problem is how t read the output of the query?
What i want is

```
 if(count=0)
{ 
   //Do
} 
else if(counnt >0)
{
    //Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use [`ExecuteScalar();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead which will return a single result.

So this line:

```
ddlistCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

should be:

```
ddlistCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

which you can then assign to `count` after type casting the result.

Comment: Note that ExecuteScalar returns object. You will need to cast the result to int.

Comment: And you have to type-cast the result.

Comment: His problem is, how to read the output of the query.  How does this have so many up votes without the answer?

Comment: @Chris - This is the answer - surely?

Comment: Can you make an edit showing how to access the count(*) stored in the ddListCmd?  I think he will accept your answer after that!

Comment: My answer already fully answers that `SqlCommand ddlistCmd` contains the result of the query which is then accessed by looking at `count`.  So `count = ddlistCmd.ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 0):

```
int result=ddlistCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
myReader.Read();
count= int.Parse(myReader[0].ToString());
```

Comment: RTFM ;) for exactly THIS there is a better wy (ExecuteScalar)