# How to use executeReader() method to retrieve the value of just one cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I need to execute the following command and pass the result to a label. I don't know how can i do it using Reader. Someone can give me a hand?

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM learer WHERE learer.id = " + index;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
learerLabel.Text = (String) cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

As you can see i create the SQL statement and i execute it, but it does not work. Why?

The console says:

> Cannot implicitly SqlDataReader to
>   String...

How can i get the desired results as String so the label can display it properly.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using select count(\*) in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701910/using-select-count-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is not recommended to use `DataReader` and `Command.ExecuteReader` to get just **one** value from the database. Instead, you should use `Command.ExecuteScalar` as following:

```
String sql = "SELECT ColumnNumber FROM learer WHERE learer.id = " + index;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
learerLabel.Text = (String) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

---

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306636) is more information about Connecting to database and managing data.

Comment: `"SELECT ColumnNumber FROM learer WHERE learer.id = " + index` may have a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability.  Instead use a parameterized query as shown in e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794580/3744182/3744182).  See: [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/3744182) and also https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries

Answer (score 50):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM learer WHERE id = @id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", index);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            learerLabel.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("somecolumn"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("somecolumn"))" is the easiest way to retrieve a text value ?

there's nothing like reader.fieldByName("Name").asString ?

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to use `ExecuteReader()` and not Scalar as the question asked

Comment: side note you cannot do this with table names just the variables

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteScalar()` is what you need here

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701910/using-select-count-in-c/5701920#5701920) which basically says use `ExecuteScalar()` instead.