# how to use executereader to read one value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, executereader

I want to read an int value from my table. but I faced with error
this is my code. please help me to edit my code.

```
    sqlc = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT RemainedCharge "
                              + " FROM aspnet_Users "
                              + " WHERE UserName = @UserName ";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", username));
    //string RemainedCharge;
    sqlc.Open();

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


       // loop over all rows returned by SqlDataReader
       while(rdr.Read())
       {
          RemainedChargeLbl.Text=rdr.GetString(0);
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

To read one value you don't need reader. Use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which executes query and returns first column of the first row in result set returned by query:

```
int value = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalcar();
```

BTW it's better to create command object with `sqlc.CreateCommand()` - it creates appropriate command and automatically assigns connection to it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794529/how-to-use-executereader-method-to-retrieve-the-value-of-just-one-cell):

```
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RemainedCharge "
                                  + " FROM aspnet_Users "
                                  + " WHERE UserName = @UserName ";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", index);
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                learerLabel.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("somecolumn"))
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning `connection object sqlc` to the `SqlCommand`.

Add this:

```
 cmd.Connection=sqlc;
```

Complete Solution:

```
sqlc = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection=sqlc;
string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT RemainedCharge "
                          + " FROM aspnet_Users "
                          + " WHERE UserName = @UserName ";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", username));
//string RemainedCharge;
sqlc.Open();

 RemainedChargeLbl.Text =((int) cmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
```