# Stored procedure Output parameter in c# is returning Empty where as Working fine while Excecuting in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure where I have a declared an output parameter. It is giving correct result when I execute it in SQL. but I intergrated it in c# code I am getting an Empty object.I am not sure what is the problem. 
I have visited so many links but didn't find any appropriate answer.

**Here is my C# function Code :-**

```
public bool PreviewAsReviewerButtonEnableDisable(string advId, string userType)
        {
            bool result = false;

            using (RMS_MVCEntities entities = new RMS_MVCEntities())
            {
                var command = entities.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "[AdvTax].[usp_PreviewAsReviewerButton_Enable_Disable]";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AdvID", advId));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Type", userType));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EnableDisable", SqlDbType.Bit));
                command.Parameters["@EnableDisable"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                entities.Database.Connection.Open();
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                result = Convert.ToBoolean(command.Parameters["@EnableDisable"].Value);
                entities.Database.Connection.Close();
            }
            return result;
}
```

**Here is my Sql Stored Procedure :-**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [AdvTax].[usp_PreviewAsReviewerButton_Enable_Disable]
@AdvID nvarchar(20),
@Type nvarchar(20),
@EnableDisable bit output
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

If @Type='CTT Maker'

Begin

Declare @Count int=(select Count(*) from [AdvTax].[AdvTax_Computation] where AdvID=@AdvID and IsActive=1)

If @Count>0

Begin
set @EnableDisable=1
End

Else

Begin
set @EnableDisable=0
End

End


If @Type='CTT Checker'

Begin

Declare @Count1 int=(select Count(*) from [AdvTax].[AdvTax_Computation_Checker]
 where AdvID=@AdvID and IsActive=1)

If @Count1>0

Begin
set @EnableDisable=1
End

Else

Begin
set @EnableDisable=0
End

End



END
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Why are you calling `ExecuteReader` when the stored procedure doesn't return any result sets?

Comment: Also, please don't *`count`* if all you care about is zero or non-zero. That's what *`exists`* is for

Comment: your proc is missing a `return`...

Comment: Use `IF EXISTS` and `IF NOT EXISTS` to check data existence. `COUNT` should only used to count records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use executeReader() method to retrieve the value of just one cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794529/how-to-use-executereader-method-to-retrieve-the-value-of-just-one-cell)

Comment: @SeM - doubt it since as I already observed, they're *not retrieving any result sets in this stored procedure*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, yes he should add `SELECT @EnableDisable` at the end of procedure, or `ExecuteNonQuery()` will work just as fine.

Comment: @SeM, I tried using `ExecuteNonQuery()` . but it is still returning empty object.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, What should I use instead of `ExecuteReader` ?

Answer (score -2):

You can try to assign it directly

```
var result = (bool)command.ExecuteReader();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `ExecuteReader` will return `SqlDataReader`, you can't cast it to `bool`.